# How can i return act_window with context in function on_change odoo 8?

Tags: onchange, odoo-8

```
def onchange_stage_id(self, cr, uid, ids, stage_id, context=None): 
    if stage.name == 'Proposal':       
        print stage.name 
        return {            
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',      
            'res_model': 'sale.order',  
            'view_type': 'form',      
            'view_mode': 'form',    
            'target': 'new',      
             }
```

when i do this onchange i got an error

`onchange_stage_values = self.onchange_stage_id(cr, uid, ids, vals.get('stage_id'), context=context)['value']`

KeyError: 'value'`

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a keyerror as the dictionary does not have any key by the name of `'value'`.

The only keys present in the dictionary that you are returning are 'type', 'res_model', 'view_type', 'view_mode', and 'target'.

If you want to access the whole dictionary:

`onchange_stage_values = self.onchange_stage_id(cr, uid, ids, vals.get('stage_id'), context=context)`

This will put the whole dictionary in `onchange_stage_values`